# Optimal OrientDB SQL query emulating a join with conditions on both sides

Tags: sql, orientdb, graph-databases, nosql

I have one vertex class "Bucket" and some other vertices classes whose name is not important.

I have an edge named "containedIn".

I want to get the optimal sql query (in terms of performance) to get all the vertices contained in a given bucket. It has to be possible to add conditions to filter the vertices. In a relational database this would be done with a simple join.

First attempt. This returns the expected vertices, but I wonder whether there is a better solution (maybe trying to avoid using a nested select?).

```
SELECT FROM 
 (SELECT expand(set(in("containedIn"))) 
  FROM Bucket 
  WHERE @rid = #5:1 ) 
WHERE @rid > #10:0  
ORDER BY @rid  
LIMIT 10000
```

I also have tried this query (only on lightweight=false mode), but I don't get the results expected. The `ORDER BY` makes it not even compile, removing the clause the query works but returns results different from what I expect.

```
SELECT expand(inV()) 
FROM containedIn 
WHERE outV("Bucket").@rid = #5:1 and inV().@rid > #10:0 
ORDER BY inV().@rid 
LIMIT 10000
```

Comment: Why do you want to filter for @rid?

Comment: In the nested select I know I could do directly FROM #5:1, it seems it is equivalent, and in the outer SELECT I use the ">" for pagination.

Answer (score 3):

FYI - In the OrientDB Studio web app, there is an 'Explain' button that shows performance information regarding a query. This is a good tool, which I used below. The same information is probably available in java, but I haven't used the java interface.

I've done some of my own testing, and it seems your original query is pretty much as good as it gets. The only unnecessary piece you have is the set() function.

Generally I would expect a WHERE clause to iterate over each record in the 'source list'. Thus, it is always best to make your 'source list' as small as possible. I'll come back to this point later.

I also note that your are using the [RID-LIMIT](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/Pagination.html#use-the-rid-limit) method of pagination recommended in the docs, which is good. I will exclude the limit from the following queries, as it kind of hides how bad some queries are.

It seems OrientDB has some shortcuts under the hood, and my testing of `SELECT FROM #1:1` and `SELECT FROM V where @rid = #1:1` revealed the time taken to always be in the same ballpark. Using the explain tool, I can see that documentReads = 1 for both.

I've got a database with ~32000 'Cities' (cluster #42) in ~700 'States' (cluster #41), linked with a lightweight edge called 'Region'. I used this for the following queries...

`SELECT FROM (SELECT expand(in('Region')) FROM #41:1) WHERE @rid > #42:1800 ORDER BY @rid`
This is the same as you have in your question. It returns 1538 records, and the explain tool shows 1633 documentReads, so this seems like an efficient query. It is very direct, as you are following edges from the '1 true source'.

`SELECT FROM City WHERE out_Region.@rid = #41:1 and @rid > #42:1800 ORDER BY @rid`
This is similar to your second query, but to suit light weight edges. It returns the same amount of records as above (1538), but the documentReads are up to 30390! This is because of the WHERE clause, as it is reading nearly every city record, then reading the state record, and checking its rid. Thus, it is probably loading every State record too (presuming every state record is linked to a city record). This query isn't direct enough.

Your second query will suffer similar problems (if you got the syntax correct), as it would read every 'containedIn' edge, then every bucket linked to those edges (so probably every bucket), and then read and return the proper records. That's a lot of reads!

You asked **"maybe trying to avoid using a nested SELECT?"**. When you do `SELECT in('Region') FROM #41:1`, you get a list of rids. It would make sense to filter these rids, and then use expand() on the shortened list. This way, only the relevant records would be read via expand(). If OrientDB wasn't smart, the query `SELECT expand(in('Region')) FROM #41:1` could be reading all of the records, but only returning a small portion (ie if the query was finding 1538 records like above, but had a limit of 100, then 1438 reads would be unnecessary). It seems OrientDB developers have considered this though, as the query `SELECT FROM (SELECT expand(in('Region')) FROM #41:1) limit 100` only does 100 documentReads.

However, `SELECT FROM (SELECT expand(in('Region')) FROM #41:1) WHERE @rid <= #42:1800` returned 95 records, and `SELECT FROM (SELECT expand(in('Region')) FROM #41:1) WHERE @rid > #42:1800 LIMIT 100` performs 195 document reads. And worse still, `SELECT FROM (SELECT expand(in('Region')) FROM #41:1) WHERE @rid > #42:1800 ORDER BY @rid LIMIT 100` performs the full 1633 documentReads (I think the ORDER BY clause is at fault). So there might optimisation available there, as the rids could be sorted and filtered from the list before the expand() function is run, but I can't think of how to do this in a query. It's probably something the developers need to address.

Comment: I assume that the ORDER BY clause implies visiting all the cities in order to sort them before picking the 100 right after #42:1800, so no further optimization is possible.

The question then is: Is the city class sorted by rid by default (so the order by RID could be omitted, or even better, ignored by orientdb)? And if not, would an index help?